# Collation with jongo

Tags: mongodb, collation, jongo

I use MongoDB via [Jongo](http://jongo.org/) (a Java client), and I need to sort results in a case-insensitive way for a particular query.

[MongoDB's documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/) states that an index should be created with a certain collation level, and that the queries should use the same configuration :

```
db.fruit.find( {type: "apple"} )
        .collation( {locale: 'en', strength: 2} )
```

Creating the index was easy; but I cannot find *where to pass the  collation configuration* with Jongo's query API.

```
Find query = myCollection.find(match);  // No .collation() method here
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a query modifier which can be set on DBCursor by implementing QueryModifier and pass it in the 'with' method:

```
friends.find().with(new QueryModifier() {
     public void modify(DBCursor cursor) {
         cursor.setCollation(
            Collation.builder().collationStrength(CollationStrength.SECONDARY).
            locale("en").
            build())
     }
}).as(Friend.class);
```